# Flymake and Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, flymake, haskell-mode

I've seen a number of older questions on this but I'm wondering if there is a more recent problem. Earlier this year I rebuilt my Ubuntu box, installed the GH system 7.6.2, and GNU Emacs 24.2.1. I've recently had some time to return to Haskell but my environment is not working nearly as well as it did on my previous machine... On my previous system the Flymake module worked wonderfully in this environment. Now it seems to only be partly functional. It no longer highlights warnings and errors, auto-saves and recompiles, etc. It will give some "tool-tip" type information when I hover the mouse over a pointer, and it attempts to help with indentation, though it gets confused as often or not.

Has anyone else experienced problems with recent versions? Any suggestions on how to repair?

Comment: I cannot help with your original problems, but newer versions of [ghc-mod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod) might serve your purposes.